# Javascript: Chaining on elements like jQuery

Tags: javascript, method-chaining

I'm trying to replicate jQuery's element manipulation to a certain extent. Now what I have found to be very useful is the `.first()` selector. I would like to be able to chain functions like this;
`getElement(selector).first().hasClass(className);`

Now, there are 2 issues with how far I've gotten (Do note that my code example is minimised, so please, no comments about error-handling.)

```
var getElement = function(selector, parent) {
  ret           = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  this.element  = ret;
  this.hasClass = function(className) {
    className.replace('.', '');
    if(this.multiple())
    {
      console.log('Cannot use hasClass function on multiple elements');
      return false;
    }
  };

  this.first = function() {
    this.element = this.element[0];
    return this;
  };
  return this;
};
```

### My current problem

If I call my function;

`var $test = getElement('.something');
//result: nodelist with .something divs`

If I call for the first element within the result;

`$test.first();
//Result: First div, perfect!`

However, now if I call `$test` again, it will replace the `elements` property with the result of `first()`, meaning I have "lost" my old values. I don't want to lose them, I only want the `first()` functions for that specific functionality. Then I want `$test` to return all elements again.
Also, recalling `first()` will now end up `undefined`, since there is only 1 element left within `this` as it has deleted the old elements from within the object.

### Another attempt

Now, I've also tried to turn it around a bit by returning the first-child instead of the entire class object;

```
this.first = function() {
  return this.element[0];
};
```

However, I will
`$test.first().hasClass(className);
//Returns ERROR, method hasClass undefined`

this is because `.hasClass` exists on the original `this`, which doesn't get returned anymore since I'm now returning the element.

I have tried to get something out of jQuery's library, though that just confused me more...

I have googled this subject, but with all the 'chaining methods' solutions I'm finding, all of them seem to be overwriting the original values of the object, which is not what I want to happen. One other solution actually required me to re-initiate the object over and over again, which did not seem very efficient to me... Any help is appreciated. I'm assuming I'm going about this completely the wrong way.

-- If you can help me, please do explain why your solution works. I really feel like if I understand this, my understanding of javascript can expand a lot further. I just need to get past this structural(?) issue.

Comment: Don't return an element (neither does jQuery), wrap it in your own class that has the functions and works on it's own context. Also note, your this is in my opinion very ambiguous there as I don't see you using a `new getElement`, which would indicate your `this` is well, not what you are expecting it to be

Comment: Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48433222/6313073#48433222) to see a way to accomplish what you want, similar to that of `jQuery` @Babydead.

Comment: @Icepickle thanks, but I do initiate it as new. However, I used a trick to do that within the function (which I've minimised the code of, for the purpose of posting it here).
AngelPolitis Checking your answer out now.

Comment: @Babydead from your response to Angels answer, it would seem that you are not using new, as you get the window back for `this`

Comment: @icepickle yeah, I got window back if I forgot to do the new thing. Fixed that already, but I didn't understand how or what the trigger for it was ahahaha. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method like `first()` should not modify `this`, it should create a new object and return that. You only use `return this;` in methods that modify an element rather than returning information derived from the element.

```
this.first = function() {
    return new getElement(this.element[0]);
};
```

And note that you have to use `new getElement` to create an object, not just `getElement`.

This also requires a change to the constructor, so it can accept either a selector string or an element:

```
var getElement = function(selector, parent) {
    var ret = typeof selector == "string" ? document.querySelectorAll(selector) : [selector];
    ...
}
```

You should also consider doing this in proper OO fashion, by putting the methods in a prototype, rather than defining them in every object.

```
var getElement = function(selector, parent) {
  var ret = typeof selector == "string" ? document.querySelectorAll(selector) : [selector];
  this.element = ret;
};

getElement.prototype.hasClass = function(className) {
  className.replace('.', '');
  if (this.multiple()) {
    console.log('Cannot use hasClass function on multiple elements');
    return false;
  }
};

getElement.prototype.first = function() {
  return new getElement(this.element[0])
};
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Very simple explanation and a simple answer as well. -- I did try it with a prototype first, actually. It didn't work out but I'm going to try it again now that I understand it a bit better. Could you give an example of how to do that, maybe? Or have a good link for it?

Comment: You should also take a look at ES6 `class` syntax.

Comment: yeah that's pretty much what I had. It must have not worked because the rest was so wrong. I am going to try this since initiating new functions for every object does seem to be wildly inefficient (logically). I have no experience with ES6 yet, but I will go deeper into it now. Thank you so much! I will replace the this.functions with prototypes tomorrow!

Comment: I don't think that `new getElement(this.elements[0])` will work.  `document.querySelectorAll()` takes a string argument, but it will be passed a DOM node.

Comment: @RickHitchcock You are correct. But I have already caught this possibility within my function. `if(typeof selector != 'string')  {  this.element = selector;  }` -- However, it would be neat for Barmar to add this to his answer for any other viewers.

Comment: Actually, it should be `this.element = [selector];`, because the rest of the code expects `this.element` to be a collection that can be indexed (it probably should be named `elements` to make it clearer). I've updated my answer to show this.

Answer (score 2):

`this` in your outer function refers to the window / global object.

Instead, return the `ret` variable itself.

In the *inner* functions (which become the object's methods), `this` acts the way you expect it to.

Here's an alternative solution, which allows chaining, even after you've called the `first` method:

```js
var getElement = function(selector, parent) {
  var ret = typeof selector == 'string' ? document.querySelectorAll(selector)
                                        : selector;

  ret.hasClass = function(className) {
    if(!this.classList) {
      console.log('Cannot use hasClass function on multiple elements');
      return false;
    } else {
      return this.classList.contains(className);
    }
  };

  ret.first = function() {
    return new getElement(this[0]);
  };
  
  return ret;
};

console.log(getElement('p').length);                   //2
console.log(getElement('p').first().innerHTML);        //abc
console.log(getElement('p').first().hasClass('test')); //true
console.log(getElement('p').first().hasClass('nope')); //fase
console.log(getElement('p').hasClass('test'));         //false (multiple elements)
```

```html
<p class="test">
  abc
</p>

<p>
  def
</p>
```

Comment: This explains why I got the entire window back when debugging it in specific situations, thanks!  I will a accept Barmar's answer first since it's been the first answer, but you get an upvote for very good explanation and simply nice work, yeah? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest would be to return a new class that contains the nodes you have selected. That would be the easiest solution, as you don't really want to mutate any of your previous selectors.

I made a small example, using some ES6 that makes a few things easier to work with, which also has a `$` to initiate the selections being made.

You would notice that first of all, any selection that is made, is just calling the native `document.querySelectorAll` but returns a new `Node` class. Both `first` and `last` methods also return those elements.

Lastly, `hasClass` should work on all elements in the current nodes selections, so it will iterate the current node, and check all classes in there, this one returns a simple bool, so you cannot continue with the method chaining there.

Any method you wish to chain, should either:

- return `this` object (the current node)
- return an element of the `this` object as a new node so any further manipulations can be done there

```js
const $ = (function(global) {
  class Node extends Array {
    constructor( ...nodes ) {
      super();
      nodes.forEach( (node, key) => {
        this[key] = node;
      });
      this.length = nodes.length;
    }
    first() {
      return new Node( this[0] );
    }
    last() {
      return new Node( this[this.length-1] );
    }
    hasClass( ...classes ) {
      const set = classes.reduce( (current, cls) => {
          current[cls] = true;
          return current;
        }, {} );
      for (let el of this) {
        for (let cls of el.classList) {
          if (set[cls]) {
            return true;
          }
        }
      }
      return false;
    }
  }
  global.$ = function( selector ) {
    return new Node( ...document.querySelectorAll( selector ) );
  };
  
  return global.$;
}(window));

let selector = $('.foo');
let first = selector.first(); // expect 1
console.log(first[0].innerHTML);
let last = selector.last();
console.log(last[0].innerHTML); // expect 4

console.log( first.hasClass('foo') ); // expect true
console.log( first.hasClass('bar') ); // expect false
console.log( selector.hasClass('foo') ); // expect true
console.log( selector.hasClass('bar') ); // expect true
```

```html
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo bar">3</div>
<div class="foo">4</div>
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I honestly do not understand one bit of this code. I'm pretty sure it's an awesome piece of code, but I do not understand it at all...

Comment: @Babydead it's just an IIFE that creates it's own scope for the declaration of the `Node` class, and the rest is a bit of ES6 and ES7 with the spread operator. The has class might be overly complex but it would account for multiple parameters and checks all the classes that are in the current `Node`

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would approach this:

1. Create a constructor, say `Search`, tasked to find the elements based on the input. Using a constructor is proper OO Programming and you also have the advantage of defining methods once in the prototype and they can be accessed by all instances.
2. Ensure that the context (`this`) is an array-like object, with numeric properties and a length, so that you can easily iterate over every matched element in the traditional way *(using `for` loops, `[].forEach` etc)*.
3. Create a function, say `getElement`, that will use the constructor and return the result without having to use the `new` keyword all the time. Since the function returns an instance of our constructor, you can chain the methods you want as you would normally do.
4. The method `first` uses the constructor to create a new instance instead of modifying the original, since its role is to return the first element, not delete everything but the first element.
5. Each time you come up with a new method you want your object to have, you can simply add it to the prototype of the constructor.

**Snippet:**

```js
;(function () {
  function Search (value) {
    var elements = [];

    /* Check whether the value is a string or an HTML element. */
    if (typeof value == "string") {
      /* Save the selector to the context and use it to get the elements. */
      this.selector = value;
      elements = document.querySelectorAll(value);
    }
    else if (value instanceof Element) elements.push(value);
      
    /* Give a length to the context. */
    this.length = elements.length;

    /* Iterate over every element and inject it to the context. */
    for (var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; i++) this[i] = elements[i];
  }

  /* The method that returns the first element in a Search instance. */
  Object.defineProperty(Search.prototype, "first", {
    value: function () {
      return new Search(this[0]);
    }
  });
  
  /* The global function that uses the Search constructor to fetch the elements. */
  window.getElement = (value) => new Search(value);
  
  /* Create a reference to the prototype of the constructor for easy access. */
  window.getElement.fn = Search.prototype;
})();

/* Get all elements matching the class, the first one, and the first's plain form. */
console.log(getElement(".cls1"));
console.log(getElement(".cls1").first());
console.log(getElement(".cls1").first()[0]);
```

```css
/* ----- CSS ----- */
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100%!important;
}
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<div id = "a1" class = "cls1"></div>
<div id = "a2" class = "cls1"></div>
<div id = "a3" class = "cls1"></div>
```

---

**Example:**

In this example, I'm adding a new method called `hasClass` to the prototype of the constructor.

```js
/* The method that returns whether the first element has a given class. */
Object.defineProperty(getElement.fn, "hasClass", {
  value: function (value) {
    return this[0].classList.contains(value);
  }
});

/* Check whether the first element has the 'cls2' class. */
console.log(getElement(".cls1").first().hasClass("cls2"));
```

```html
<!----- HTML ----->
<script src="//pastebin.com/raw/e0TM5aYC"></script>
<div id = "a1" class = "cls1 cls2"></div>
<div id = "a2" class = "cls1"></div>
<div id = "a3" class = "cls1"></div>
```

Comment: Hmm you seem to be doing a lot of extra things that I didn't do in my original function (though I also did a lot more in my function). Anyway, why do you do the pushes and for loops when `querySelectorAll` returns a valid array which you can just count the length of?

Comment: The pushes happen only when the argument is an element. If it's a selector, then `querySelectorAll` is used. Also, the `for` loop is necessary to transfer the elements from the `nodelist` `querySelectorAll` returns to the `this` object, so that the prototype methods can access them @Babydead. And actually, I'm not doing extra stuff at all. Imagine if you wanted to be able to pass the `document`, or `window` or whatever inside the function; maybe even use a context. I'm being very basic here 

Comment: Thank you for explaning. I think I'll have to dive deeper into your answer when I get the time. It's still a bit complicated for me!

Comment: You should surely do. I've written the code in the cleanest possible way and commented it, so that you read it and understand every step with ease. I hope it'll prove useful to you in some occasion @Babydead.

Comment: it will. I'm going to study it to become better at it. I will try your method on my next class!

Answer (score -1):

You can update `getElement` so it returns back again when you send it an element.

```js
var getElement = function(selector, parent) {
  var ret = null
  if (typeof selector === "string") {
    ret = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
  } else {
    ret = selector
  }
  this.element = ret;
  this.hasClass = function(className) {
    className.replace('.', '');
    if (this.multiple()) {
      console.log('Cannot use hasClass function on multiple elements');
      return false;
    }
  };

  this.first = function() {
    this.element = getElement(this.element[0]);
    return this;
  };
  return this;
};

var test = getElement(".foo");
console.log(test.first())
console.log(test.first().hasClass)
```

```html
<div class="foo">1</div>
<div class="foo">2</div>
<div class="foo">3</div>
<div class="foo">4</div>
```

Comment: wouldn't `this` just be `window` or the global object in your example?

Answer (score -2):

You can use `.querySelectorAll()`, spread element and `Array.prototype.find()`, which returns the first match within an array or `undefined`

```js
const getElement = (selector = "", {prop = "", value = "", first = false} = {}) => {
    const el = [...document.querySelectorAll(selector)];
    if (first) return el.find(({[prop]:match}) => match && match === value)
    else return el;
};

let first = getElement("span", {prop: "className", value: "abc", first: true});
    
console.log(first);

let last = getElement("span");

console.log(all);
```

```html
<span class="abc">123</span>
<span class="abc">456</span>
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with my question

Comment: @Babydead The Question is _"Javascript: Chaining on elements like jQuery"_, which is what the code at the Answer does, by utilizing `Array.prototype` methods. What is the issue with the solution to your inquiry at the code at the above Answer?

Comment: @AngelPolitis spread syntax is not an operator [What is SpreadElement in ECMAScript documentation? Is it the same as Spread operator at MDN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37151966/what-is-spreadelement-in-ecmascript-documentation-is-it-the-same-as-spread-oper?)

Comment: Microsoft [disagrees](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/scripting/javascript/reference/spread-operator-decrement-dot-dot-dot-javascript).

Comment: @AngelPolitis That description is not accurate relevant to the specification.

Comment: Never mind, thanks for the link. Felix Kling's answer was very informative. Naming conventions can become confusing at times.